# c++ repeated arrow operator dereferencing performance vs dot operator

Tags: c++

Arrow dereferencing `p->m` is syntactic sugar for `(*p).m`, which appears like it might involve two separate memory lookup operations--one to find the object on the heap and the second to then locate the member field offset.

This made me question whether there is any performance difference between these two code snippets.  Assume `classA` has 30+ disparate fields of various types which need to be accessed in various orders (not necessarily consecutively or contiguously):

*Version 1:*

```
void func(classA* ptr)
{
  std::string s = ptr->field1;
  int i = ptr->field2;
  float f = ptr->field3;
  // etc...
}
```

*Version 2:*

```
void func(classA* ptr)
{
  classA &a = *ptr;
  std::string s = a.field1;
  int i = a.field2;
  float f = a.field3;
  // etc...
}
```

So my question is whether or not there is a difference in performance (even if very slight) between these two versions, or if the compiler is smart enough to make them equivalent (even if the different field accesses are interrupted by many lines of other code in between them, which I did not show here).

Comment: If no one knows the answer I will have to microbenchmark it myself. However I'd like the answer to be available to others in the future.

Comment: Measure it... or compare the assembly output, you can even do it online https://gcc.godbolt.org/

Comment: Well, it's easy enough for you to find the answer to this on your own by just timing it in your code or using a profiler.

Comment: Isn't that resolved at compile time?

Comment: You can also inspect the assembly code, because most compilers would perform the same operations for references and pointers. See here: 
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/214997/reference-vs-dereference-pointers-in-arguments-c-c

Comment: No offense, but the answer to this question has little merit for others. This is not a place where "optimization" can have an astounding effect.

Comment: I fail to see *how* these two implementations could be any different.

Comment: All you've done is create an alias to the pointer so you won't see any gain.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Thanks, that was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Arrow dereferencing p->m is syntactic sugar for (*p).m

That isn't generally true, but is true in the limited context in which you are asking.

> which appears like it might involve two separate memory lookup
>   operations--one to find the object on the heap and the second to then
>   locate the member field offset.

Not at all.  It is one to read the parameter or local variable holding the pointer and the second to access the member.  But any reasonable optimizer would keep the pointer in a register in the code you showed, so no extra access.

But your alternate version also has a local pointer, so no difference anyway (at least in the direction you're asking about):

```
  classA &a = *ptr;
```

Assuming the whole function is not being inlined or assuming for some other reason the compiler doesn't know exactly where `ptr` points, the `&` must use a pointer, so either the compiler can deduce it is safe for `a` to be an alias of `*ptr` so there is **NO** difference, or the compiler must make `a` an alias of `*copy_of_ptr` so the version using a `&` is slower (not faster as you seem to have expected) by the cost of copying `ptr`.

> even if the different field accesses are interrupted by many lines of
>   other code in between them, which I did not show here

That moves you toward the interesting case.  If that intervening code could change `ptr` then obviously the two versions behave differently.  But what if a human can see that the intervening code **can't** change `ptr` while a compiler can't see that:  Then the two versions are semantically equal, but the compiler doesn't know that and the compiler may generate **slower** code for the version you tried to hand optimize by creation of a reference.

Comment: Thanks, your answer makes sense. I guess the mental hiccup I had was failing to realize *Version 2* still requires the exact same pointer lookups as *Version 1*. You are correct that in the best case, *Version 2* will be "as fast as" *Version 1*, and in the worst case it could be slightly slower.

Answer (score 2):

Most (?all) compilers implement references as pointers under the hood, so I would expect no difference in the generated assembly (apart from a possible copy to initialize a reference - but I would expect the optimizer to eliminate even that).

In general, this sort of micro-optimization is not worth it.  It is always preferable to concentrate on clear and correct code.  It is *certainly* not worth this sort of optimization until you have measured where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Most compilers implement **difficult** uses of references as pointers under the hood.  Easy uses of reference are implemented as compile time aliases.  `int&a=x;`  `a` may be just another name for `x` at compile time.  `a` may not need any implementation of its own.

Comment: Ish.  The same is true of pointers. `int *p = &x;` `*p` may be just another name for `x` at compile time, `p` may not need any implementation of its own.